# How to enable Application insights for static website which is hosting in Azure storage account?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-static-website-hosting

I have an Angular application and it is deployed as a static website in Azure storage account. I use the following code to set up Application Insights in my app. After deployment, I can not see any trace data in my App Insights workspace.

```
  loadApplicationInsights() {
    this._initAppInsights();
    this._appInsights?.loadAppInsights();
  }

  logException(exception: Error, severityLevel?: number) {
    this._appInsights?.trackException({ exception: exception, severityLevel: severityLevel });
  }

  logTrace(message: string, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    this._appInsights?.trackTrace({ message: message}, properties);
  }
  private _initAppInsights() {
    const { enableInsights, instrumentationKey } = this._appConfig.envConfig.applicationInsights || { enableInsights: false, instrumentationKey: null };

    if (enableInsights && instrumentationKey){
      this._appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
        config: {
          instrumentationKey,
          enableAutoRouteTracking: true,
        }
      });

   }
  }
```

This setting works when I deploy the app to Azure web app. What needs to be adjusted for static website hosting in Azure storage account?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Install `npm install --save @microsoft/applicationinsights-web`  in your Angular application.

[image]

- Then, configure application insights. You can do this in your Angular service or component.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TelemetryService {
  private appInsights: ApplicationInsights;

  constructor() {
    this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
      config: {
        instrumentationKey: 'YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY',
        enableAutoRouteTracking: true,
      },
    });
    this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();
  }

  logTrace(message: string, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    this.appInsights.trackTrace({ message: message }, properties);
  }

  // Add other telemetry methods as needed (e.g., logException).
}
```

- Check the code that initializes Application Insights is executed when the application loads.

[image]

- Then Deploy the application to the Azure Storage Account as a static website.

[image]

Configure CORS rules to allow requests from your static website's domain. This is crucial for Application Insights to send telemetry data to the correct endpoint.